# Can $f :(\Bbb R, +) \to (\Bbb R, +)$ be a homomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

**QUESTION**: Is there a homomorphism

$$f :(\Bbb R, +) \to (\Bbb R, +)$$

that does not have the form $x \mapsto ax$, where $a\in\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: I take it from the answers that you meant a homomorphism of additive groups, not a linear map?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: This has been asked more than a handful of times before. See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/423492/overview-of-basic-facts-about-cauchy-functional-equation for details.

Comment: There is also the other side.  If such a homomorphism is measurable, then it *does* have the form $ax$.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, using the Axiom of Choice.
The abelian group $\mathbb R$ is an infinite-dimensional vector space over the field $\mathbb Q$. Unfortuately, one cannot give an explicit basis of this vector space, but the linear map of "swapping" two of the basis vectors, say, is a nontrivial automorphism of $\mathbb R$ as abelian group that is not of the form $x\mapsto ax$.

Comment: Neat,  never thought of it like this

Comment: If we can't give a construction of the basis of this infinite-dimensional vector space, and thus can't know the actual results of the group operation, how do we know that this isn't just a more complicated way of mapping $x\mapsto ax$?

Comment: @PeterOlson Because we can specify an initial part of the basis, say $1, \sqrt 2, \sqrt{3}, \pi, e,\ldots$. Then the linear map "swap the $1$ and $\sqrt 2$ components" would map $42\mapsto 42\sqrt 2$ (so $a$ must be $\sqrt 2$) and $\sqrt 3+7\pi-4+\sqrt 2\mapsto \sqrt 3+7\pi-4\sqrt 2+1$ (which doesn't match $a=\sqrt 2$). Alternatively, one could ppick a nontrivial map with nontrivial kernel.

Comment: Another way to view it is that a homomorphism of the form $x\mapsto ax$ preserves order. If you swap two basis elements, as suggested by Peter Olson, the newly constructed homomorphism no longer preserves order.